# SQLite and SQL Server CE database file missing using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, sql-server-ce

I'm using Entity Framework code-first and my database file is apparently not being created, not on disk at least. I can use the database with my program, everything works great, the only problem is that I cannot find the database file it self, which I would like to use for debugging purposes.

This is my `DbContext` class:

```
public class HelperEntities : DbContext
{
        public HelperEntities() : base("HelperEntities") { }

        public DbSet<GuidModel> Guids { get; set; }
}
```

Connection string:

```
<add name="HelperEntities" connectionString="Data Source=NewDatabase.sdf;Encrypt Database=True;Password:nopassword1;" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe" />
```

This happens both with SQL Server Compact Edition and SQLite

Comment: Look in your bin/debug folder! Best apporach is to have full path to your database file in connection string

Comment: It's not on the build folder and even if I specify a specific folder as "C:\database.sdf" it won't be there.

Comment: It's probably in you user profile folder (Windows 7 `C:\Users\username`).